# How to resolve Macro length exceeds 2500 lines, this might take too long to load

Tags: windows, imacros

[image]

How can we resolve this issue?.

> Macro length exceeds 2500 lines, this might take too long to load. Would you like to proceed? Note: You can disable this warning message
>   by increasing the "extensions.imacros.maxMacroLength" parameter.

Comment: Erm *You can disable this warning message by increasing the "extensions.imacros.maxMacroLength" parameter.*

Comment: this (extensions.imacros.maxMacroLength) is not showing in my Mozilla about:config

Answer (score 2):

extensions.imacros.maxMacroLength problem, type in address about:config,
then press i promise i be careful
in search type or copy and paste   extensions.imacros.maxMacroLength

if it does not show add a new one by right clicking the main window
click new, then integer then paste the words "extensions.imacros.maxMacroLength" .
then type a value higher than the lines in your script

and problem solved

best regards letsdancemusic

Comment: This solution worked for me. I'm not sure why someone else gave you a downvote.

Comment: not sure why they down vote but its good it worked for you, must be cause I mentioned a beginner programmer might not use loops but have repeated commands that exceed macro line limits. Not everyone start of advance programming and need to learn or like to see line by line or see what line it gets to

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the message with "extensions.imacros.maxMacroLength" in your about:config adress in Mozilla. If this doesnt exist, simply create it.

Answer (score -1):

If you script has repeated instructions shorten the script down and use the "play loop" and increase "max" setting how many times you want the script to repeat, i find anything over 10,000 lines begans to stall the script to start longer the script the longer it takes to load into memory

Comment: a beginner programmer, or someone who want to count lines as it progresses thru the script. might sound silly to a veteran programmer people like to have options opened